# spring-kafka snapshot builds exist somewhere?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm in need of code that only exists in the master at the moment, and the docs specifically mention a version called 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, but I'll be damned if I can figure out which repository is hosting such a build.  Anyone have any clues?

Also, is there any information published about release schedules?  I'm loath to develop against the 1.x API because I want the retry and recovery functionality (which doesn't work in either of the 2.0.0 milestone builds, hence my need for a snapshot), but I don't want to commit to an unreleased library without some sense of when a release might happen.

Answer (score 1):

The BUILD-SNAPSHOT you can find in the https://repo.spring.io/snapshot. So, you should configure that for your project.

The next Spring Kafka 2.0.0.RC1 is scheduled for this June 28.

You can find that info on the project page as well: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/milestone/20

Comment: See the [project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/) - at the "Quick Start" select a snapshot from the dropdown and you will see the repository. `libs-snapshot` referenced there is a virtual repo covering snapshots, milestones and releases `.../snapshot` alone is just snapshots. As @Artem says, the release candidate is due at the end of the month with the GA a couple of weeks later (soon after Spring Framework 5.0 ships).

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to get at is that there is no documentation, anywhere that I can find, which states what the release milestones are, when they are scheduled, what the dependencies are, etc.  There is nothing to indicate that spring-kafka 2.0.0 is at all related to spring-boot 2.0.0, or that either of them is dependent on spring-framework 5.0.0. Similarly, this answer says the milestone can be found on the project page and provides a link - but DISCOVERING that link from the project page is a near impossibility - especially for someone not accustomed to github

Comment: How about this https://spring.io/blog/2017/04/27/spring-for-apache-kafka-2-0-milestone-1-available ?